# best practice on conditional queries with linq to entities

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I often find myself writing querys like this:

```
var voyages = db.VoyageRequests.Include("Carrier")
              .Where(u => (fromDate.HasValue ? u.date >= fromDate.Value : true) &&
                    (toDate.HasValue ? u.date <= toDate.Value : true) &&
                    u.Carrier != null &&
                    u.status == (int)VoyageStatus.State.InProgress)
              .OrderBy(u => u.date);

            return voyages;
```

With conditionals inside the where statement:

```
fromDate.HasValue ? u.date >= fromDate.Value : true
```

I know the other way to do it'll be like:

```
 var voyages = db.VoyageRequests.Include("Carrier").Where(u => u.Carrier != null &&
                            u.status == (int)VoyageStatus.State.InProgress);

            if (fromDate.HasValue)
            {
                voyages = voyages.Where(u => u.date >= fromDate.Value);
            }

            if (toDate.HasValue)
            {
                voyages = voyages.Where(u => u.date <= toDate.Value);
            }

            return voyages.OrderBy(u => u.date);
```

Is there any real difference that may affect performance when this 2 approaches get transform to SQL expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query will create the simpler SQL because the evaluation of `fromDate.HasValue` and `toDate.HasValue` happens on the client. In the first query the ternary operators get evaluated on the database server as part of the SQL query. Both `fromDate` and `toDate` will be transmitted as constants to the server while in the second query only then if `.HasValue` is `true`.

We are talking about a few bytes more in length of the SQL statement and I don't believe that the server-side evaluation of the ternaries has any significant effect on query performance.

I would choose what you find more readable. Personally I would decide for the second query.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the simple SQL and the more readable C# you can create an Extension as suggested by Viktor Mitev http://mentormate.com/blog/improving-linq-to-entities-queries/

```
public static class WhereExtensions
{
   // Where extension for filters of any nullable type
   public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<Tsource, TFilter>
              (
                 this IQueryable <TSource> source, 
                 Nullable <TFilter> filter, 
                 Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate
              ) where TFilter : struct
   {
       if (filter.HasValue)
       {
           source = source.Where(predicate);
       }

       return source;
   }

    // Where extension for string filters
   public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>
             (
                this IQueryable<TSource> source,   
                string filter, 
                Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate
             )
   {
       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter))
       {
           source = source.Where(predicate);
       }

       return source;
   }

    // Where extension for collection filters
   public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource, TFilter>
             (
                this IQueryable<TSource> source, 
                IEnumerable<TFilter> filter, 
                Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate
             )
 {
     if (filter != null && filter.Any())
     {
         source = source.Where(predicate);
     }

     return source;
 }
```

Then your "secound query" will look like this:

```
var voyages = db.VoyageRequests.Include("Carrier")
.Where(u => u.Carrier != null && u.status == (int)VoyageStatus.State.InProgress)
    .Where(u => u.date >= fromDate)
    .Where(u => u.date <= toDate)
    .OrderBy(u => u.date);
```

I don't know if it is more readable or if it will be confusing for some developers because it is more difficult to read directly form the code what part of the filtering is in use.

Maybe it will be more readable if you name the extensions function something like WhereIfFilterNotNull (or something meaningful :-)

```
var voyages = db.VoyageRequests.Include("Carrier")
.Where(u => u.Carrier != null && u.status == (int)VoyageStatus.State.InProgress)
    .WhereIfFilterNotNull(u => u.date >= fromDate)
    .WhereIfFilterNotNull(u => u.date <= toDate)
    .OrderBy(u => u.date);
```